# How to take input of different data types in single line separated by space

Tags: python, python-3.x, user-input

I want the input `BANANA FRIES 12` to be stored in *dish, price*.I can't even use `dish, price = [i for i in input().split()]`.How can i store them if i am using python 3

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You actually could, if the input was limited to one word, e.g.

```
"HAMBURGER 12"
```

Your problem is that it *looks* like you're only interested in what's after the last split. Luckily if you [read the docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.rsplit) you'll find that there's an `rsplit` method. And it, too, has a maxsplit argument:

```
dish, price = input().rsplit(None, 1)
```

No need for the list comprehension - split & friends already return one. If you use `None` as the first argument then it defaults to searching for any amount of whitespace, so

```
In [1]: "BANANA FRIES \t\t\n 42".rsplit(None, 1)
Out[1]: ['BANANA FRIES', '42']
```

Comment: If it worked for you, the correct thing to do is mark the answer as accepted by clicking the check mark `<----`. When it turns green, that means you've accepted the answer.